# German characters not shown in powershell form

Tags: powershell, encoding

It is possible to show special german  characters like “ä ü ö” in a powershell form? Because right now the characters are replaced with some weird characters.
Right now i have something like

```
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
$Label1.Text = "ä ü ö"
$form1.Controls.Add($Label1)
```

And the output is something like in this picture : [weird charachters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjPWK.png) .
I tried to search on the internet and I know that the problem is from the encoding, but I don't know how to integrate this in my script and didn't find the correct script line which will solve the problem.

L.E: I need this piece of code to work in ps1 file ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF8 Script in PowerShell outputs incorrect characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482253/utf8-script-in-powershell-outputs-incorrect-characters)

Comment: @JosefZ This answer to my question partially. I think I know the problem and how to fix it but I don't know the command to set UTF8withBOM ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but too much text for a comment...

I've added some missing bits from your sample, and the following works fine for me here:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
$Label1.Text = "ä ü ö"
$form1.Controls.Add($Label1)

$form1.ShowDialog();
```

[image]

Comment: This is working if you type this in the powershell console, but is not working if you put them into ps1 script and run with the comand powershell -file filename.ps1 ...

Comment: It’s probably the encoding of your *.ps1 file then - try saving it as UTF8 in your text editor and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Oh, i get it now. Thank you!