# Learn Python 3 The Hard way Ex.23 - Characters not showing in powershell

Tags: python, powershell

Very beginner question. While trying to run the script written in LP3THW Ex.23, PowerShell isn't displaying foreign characters. I'm assuming it has to do with UTF16 / UTF8 encoding but I can't figure it out from other posts on stack overflow.

Here is the script:

```
import sys
script, input_encoding, error = sys.argv


def main(language_file, encoding, errors):
    line = language_file.readline()
    
    if line:
        print_line(line, encoding, errors)
        return main(language_file, encoding, errors)
        
        
def print_line(line, encoding, errors):
    next_lang = line.strip()
    raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding, errors=errors)
    cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, errors=errors)
    
    print(raw_bytes, "<===>", cooked_string)
    
    
languages = open("languages.txt", encoding="utf-8")

main(languages, input_encoding, error)
```

The text file contents (Languages.txt) can be seen here: https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/languages.txt

Image of PowerShell terminal when running script:
[image]

Links of other posts which make me even more confused:

[Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8)

[UTF8 Script in PowerShell outputs incorrect characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482253/utf8-script-in-powershell-outputs-incorrect-characters)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

- **Unicode character *rendering***:

  - The **default font in regular console windows is limited in terms of the Unicode characters it can display**, and many of those present in your sample file are *not* supported.
  - While you can try to switch to a different font that (hopefully) can render all the characters you need - as described in [one of the answers you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8) - **consider switching to [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)**, installable from the Microsoft store: it provides support for a much wider range of characters by default.
- **PowerShell's interpretation of UTF-8 text files *without a BOM***:

  - In ***Windows PowerShell*** - which is what you're using, judging by the screen shot - **BOM-less text files are assumed to be *ANSI-encoded***, i.e. to be encoded with the legacy ANSI code page based on your machine's system locale (language for non-Unicode programs), such as Windows-1252 on US-English systems.
  - ***PowerShell (Core) 7+*, by contrast, now commendably assumes UTF-8**, and generally uses BOM-less UTF-8 as the *consistent* default (including when *writing* files).
  - Therefore, **to *decode* the file properly, use `Get-Content -Encoding Utf8 languages.txt` in Windows PowerShell**.

    - Note: This in turn may reveal *rendering problems* due to lack of support for certain Unicode characters in the active font, but in Windows Terminal you'd see the expected output.
- **Python's *output* character encoding**:

  - If you're only **printing *directly to the console*, your script's content will appear correctly**, barring any rendering problems due to unsupported characters. The reason is that Python detects this output scenario and use a Unicode-enabled API to print.
  - **More work is needed if you need to *further process* the output**, such as by capturing it in a variable, sending it to another command, or saving it to a file:

    - **Python defaults to *ANSI*(!) encoding on output to stdout**, so it must be **instructed to output UTF-8 instead**, which can you do by setting `$env:PYTHONUTF8=1` beforehand or passing `-X utf8` on the `python` / `py` command line (v3.7+).
    - Complementarily, **PowerShell must (temporarily) be instructed to expect UTF-8 output from external programs** (instead of the output encoded with the legacy OEM code page), which requires executing `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()`

To put it all together in the form of a sample PowerShell script (`.ps1`):

```
# PREREQUISITES:
#  * In a *regular console window*: 
#    Choose a font that supports all characters in language.txt, if possible
#  * Preferably, run from *Windows Terminal*.
#  Additionally, the code assumes:
#    * Windows 10 or higher.
#    * Python 3.7 or higher.

# Download the sample file.
# It contains a list of language names expressed in each language natively,
# therefore containing many non-ASCII-range characters, including CJK ones.
curl.exe -O https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/languages.txt

# Print the sample file using a PowerShell command.
# Assuming you've chosen a suitable font or are running from Windows Terminal, 
# all non-ASCII-range should characters correctly.
Get-Content -Encoding Utf8 languages.txt

pause

# Invoke your Python script file and let it *print directly to the console*.
# Again, this should render the non-ASCII-range characters correctly.
python script.py utf8 strict

pause

# Invoke it again, but with further processing, which requires
#  * requesting that Python use UTF-8
#  * making PowerShell expect UTF-8

# (Temporarily) tell PowerShell to expect UTF-8 stdout output 
# from external programs.
$prevEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()

# Invoke the Python script, telling Python to output UTF-8 to stdout.
# Select-Object -Firt 10 limits the output to the first 10 lines.
# Note that this operation alone involves decoding of Python's output by PowerShell.
# Again, this should render the non-ASCII-range characters correctly.
python -X utf8 script.py utf8 strict | Select-Object -First 10

[Console]::OutputEncoding = $prevEncoding
```